# Can't start mysqld_safe on linux

Tags: mysql, linux, low-memory

I've downloaded mysql binaries and I'm trying to follow instructions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/unix-postinstallation.html) for installation. when I try to run `bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &` command I get the following output:

> 40211 19:04:56 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/irpowerweb.err'.
>   140211 19:04:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
>   140211 19:04:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/irpowerweb.pid ended

The content of the error log is:

```
140211 19:07:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2014-02-11 19:07:02 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
InnoDB: mmap(68370432 bytes) failed; errno 12
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] Binlog end

...
Shutting down stuff
...

2014-02-11 19:07:02 19511 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140211 19:07:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/irpowerweb.pid ended
```

Here's `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64M    
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

I just want to get mysql running in w/e way. I tried installing the package using `yum install mysql-server`, downloading rpm packages and failed to get it started. I settled for simple tar package and started following the link above but then again I failed to get it started.
Since the error states `Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool` I tried reducing the memory to 64m (default was 128m) and it didn't work.
I'm a newbie in this, I've done a lot of searching around and haven't figured out how to fix this.

P.S. If it help, I'm using ssh to connect to a server with low memory (512MB of memory with no swap), and I think it's a red hat Linux.

Comment: can you post your `my.cnf` file?

Comment: The system has 512MB of memory, using the `free` command I can see that most of it is available (about 450MB), SO I think I have enough to get mysql started.

Comment: Disbable all the engines you don't need, and configure mysqld to use as little memory as possible. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this by googling `low memory mysql`

Comment: Your most significant error is `Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool` try to lower it in `my.cnf`. Also, what distro are you on?

Comment: @Oerd I did try lowering it from 128 to 64, still doesn't work. It's a red hat and I think it's CentOS.

Comment: @atoMerz: look at your my.cnf comments: "Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%" emphasis on `else 10%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/502025/209055). Used the following my.cnf and it worked:

```
[mysqld] 
innodb=OFF 
ignore-builtin-innodb 
skip-innodb
default-storage-engine=myisam 
default-tmp-storage-engine=myisam
```

Answer (score 1):

Your most significant error is:

> Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

You'll have to lower it, in `my.cnf`.

When you run `free`, `mysqld_safe` is already done cleaning up, so you'd have to monitor memory via another terminal. But it's quite normal that a default `my.cnf` will use up your available memory. This is one of the reasons why Debian does not ship with a default my.cnf config.

**update**:
just in case, make sure to:

- Follow [MySQL Tuner](https://raw.github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl)'s  advices for your system.
- Make sure SELinux is either turned off or set to allow mysql
- Make sure your stack size is large enough using `ulimit -s` (you can increase it: `ulimit -s <new_size>` or even `ulimit -s unlimited`)

Comment: Tried lowering `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 32M, 16M and 8M. first 2 failed with a lengthy error log and last one failed with `InnoDB: Error: pthread_create returned 11`.

Comment: some more things you can try

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
[mysqld]
...
skip-bdb
skip-innodb
```

This will stop the Berkley DB and InnoDB from being started at all.

Comment: `skip-bdb` is unknown parameter so I removed it. After that the errlog is `2014-02-11 19:48:07 5424 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-02-11 19:48:07 5424 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
2014-02-11 19:48:07 5424 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-02-11 19:48:07 5424 [ERROR] Aborting
`

Comment: did you disable all the other innodb configuration options?

Comment: I did that and still the same error: `Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB`.

Comment: ok, try setting default-storage-engine=myisam or passing --default-storage-engine=myisam when you start mysql

Comment: Turned out I had to set `default-tmp-storage-engine` too: http://serverfault.com/a/502025/209055